# EF Core adding discriminator column to owned entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

So my entity has two properties with an owned entity. For some reason EF Core is adding a discriminator column to one of them. It would be great if someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or if there is some weird bug here.

This is the whole entity even though I suspect only `Requested` and `Approved` is relevant.

```
public class Absence
    {
        public Absence()
        {
            Requested = new AuditInfo();
            Approved = new AuditInfo();
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        public AbsenceType Type { get; set; }
        public AbsenceState State { get; set; }

        public AuditInfo Requested { get; set; }
        public AuditInfo Approved { get; set; }

        public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AbsenceDay> Days { get; set; }

    }
```

`Absence` doesn't have any special mappings but AuditInfo is mapped as

```
x.Owned<AuditInfo>();
```

This mostly generate the expected SQL, except this weird item:

[image]

This also leads to the code failing at runtime with this message:

```
Message: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
---- System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ApprovedA_Discriminator', table 'bokio-test.dbo.Absences'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

**What I have tried:**

I tried mapping the items like this which makes no difference:

```
        x.Entity<Absence>().OwnsOne(x1 => x1.Approved);
        x.Entity<Absence>().OwnsOne(x1 => x1.Requested);
```

I tried renaming `Approved` to `ApprovedA` which made no difference.

I then tried a small repro like this which **doesn't** create a discriminator column:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public Address WorkAddress { get; set; }

}
```

Now I'm out of ideas and need some help.

---

**Update 1:**

Hold your hats, things are about to get really weird!

When I rename `Approved` to `Donkey` the discriminator column goes away

[image]

Almost stranger is that when I try to repro it with the name Approved in the small test I still don't get the discriminator column there.

---

**Update 2:**

So I tried a bunch of other names. Success means no discriminator column.

Xpproved = success
App = fail
Ap = fail
CrAp = success
A = fail
Axx = success
ApprovedXX = fail
XApproved = success

That inspired me to try this solution with XApproved which **works**

```
x.Entity<Absence>().OwnsOne(x1 => x1.XApproved, o =>
{
    o.Property(x2 => x2.Ip).HasColumnName("Approved_Ip");
    o.Property(x2 => x2.UserAgent).HasColumnName("Approved_UserAgent");
    o.Property(x2 => x2.UserId).HasColumnName("Approved_UserId");
    o.Property(x2 => x2.TimeUtc).HasColumnName("Approved_TimeUtc");
});
```

---

**Update 3:**

AuditInfo only has these properties and no mappings beside being `Owned`. It does have a bunch of classes inheriting it though:

```
public DateTime TimeUtc { get; set; }
public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
public string Ip { get; set; }
public string UserAgent { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can we see that `AuditInfo` class? But the real one - with base classes etc. Also do you have class which inherits `AuditInfo`?

Comment: Updated with the info + some more tests I ran on the names.

Comment: It has to be related to inheritance - `Discriminator` column is indication of TPH.

Comment: @Ivan might be on to something. You mention that  things inherit from AuditInfo.  When you tried it with the addresses, did anything inherit from the addresses?

Comment: 'Inheritance hierarchies that include owned entity types are not supported'  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#limitations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't fully understand the issue (why changing the name made the problem go away) I noticed that it didn't really solve the problem. But rather just moved it around. The comment comment from @philreed above was what really made it click.

`AuditInfo` was inherited by another Owned Entity `ClosurePart`. By changing from

```
public class AuditInfo {
...props here
}

public class ClosurePart : AuditInfo {}
```

to

```
public class AuditInfoCommon {
...props here
}

public class AuditInfo : AuditInfoCommon {}

public class ClosurePart : AuditInfoCommon {}
```

The problem went away fully without needing the hacks.

**NOTE:** AuditInfoCommon is not mapped into the model!